# Existence and uniqueness of the minimizer of Moreau-Yosida approximation

Tags: calculus, optimization, hilbert-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $f:H\to\mathbb{R}$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space, be a function that is bounded below, convex ($f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y) \text{ for all } x,y\in H \text{ and } 0\leq t\leq 1$), and lower semi-continuous.

Let $x\in H$ and $t>0$. Define

\begin{equation}
F_t(y) = tf(y)+||x-y||^2.
\end{equation}

Show that there exists a unique $y_t\in H$ such that $\displaystyle F_t(y_t)=\min_{y\in H} F_t(y)$.

I have no idea how to do this problem, especially the existence of the minimizer. Is it because the functions are bounded below, there is a minimum value? How about the uniqueness?

Thank you.

Comment: Not exactly what you want: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/136402/27978

Comment: Note that uniqueness follows because $x\mapsto \|x\|^2$ is strictly convex. Existence follows from the link above, with minor modifications to deal with the fact that $f$ is lsc. rather than continuous. There may be as simpler way, but it eludes me at present.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does the fact that $f$ is bounded below have any use for the proof of the existence? Can you also elaborate on the uniqueness? Thanks again.

Comment: I added some comments in an answer below, as they were too long to fit in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it won't fit in the comments.

Set $t=1$ in the above, it has no effect on the following.

The fact that $f$ is bounded below allows us to conclude that $F_1$ is bounded below. Other conditions are possible, for example, if $f$ majorises some linear functional, or if $f$ is continuous at some point.

The proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/136464/27978) relies on the epigraph (of $F_1$ in this case) being closed
and bounded below. Then weak compactness of a 'clipped' version of the epigraph is used to show existence of a minimiser.

For uniqueness:

The polarisation identity can be used to get
$\|x-{1 \over 2} (y_1+y_2)\|^2 = {1 \over 2} \|x-y_1\|^2 + {1 \over 2} \|x-y_2\|^2 - {1 \over 4} \|y_1-y_2\|^2$, combining this with convexity of $f$
gives
$F_1({1 \over 2} (y_1+y_2)) \le {1 \over 2} F_1(y_1) + {1 \over 2} F_1(y_2)- {1 \over 4} \|y_1-y_2\|^2$.

Hence if $y_1 \neq y_2$ were two minimisers, we would have an immediate contradiction.